# QueryDSL with Spring Data MongoDB - contains all

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I wanted to achieve something similar to `contains all`, but I couldn't find any support for [mongodb - $all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), so I tried to do this by hand.

My entity has a simple set of `tags` - `Set<String>`.

```kotlin
val taskEntity = QTaskEntity.taskEntity
val where = BooleanBuilder()

where.and(taskEntity.tags.contains("a"))
where.and(taskEntity.tags.contains("b"))
```

But the generated query only takes `b` into consideration, `a` is completely ignored.

`find using query: { "tags" : "b" }...`

What's more: I also have another filter to find `tasks` that have any of the specified `tags` (`contains any`) - it works by using mongodb `$in` as expected:

```kotlin
where.and(taskEntity.tags.any().`in`(["a", "b"])))
...
find using query: { "tags" : { "$in" : ["a", "b"] } }
```

But if I combine both of those then the `contains any` is ignored and the result is the same as with the first snippet.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug or something that cannot be done on mongodb side? Could kotlin be at fault here (generated classes look fine to me)? Is this something that can be done in mongodb only through the `$all` mentioned before and querydsl doesn't support it?

Comment: What is your sample data looks like and what is your expected result?